# Stackoverflow Score Not Updating

Tags: support, status-norepro, stack-overflow, reputation

I'm, recently answered a whole bunch of questions on Stackoverflow, but they've not modified my score.  Is there any reason would this be happening?  I doubt it is a bug, but just wanted to check, just in case :)

Comment: The last few answers you posted to SO were on community wiki questions, so no rep is awarded.  I upvoted one of your normal answers and your reputation properly incremented.

Comment: feel free to upvote any one of my answers and i will tell you if i get the points in time...

seriously, i, too, have seen a bit of latency, but it is all good in the end, who really cares about the points.  if you are competing there is a guy named Jon that is going to win.

Comment: I have **never** seen latency in rep... and I've been looking for "a while "(trying, and failing, to chase said Jon)

Comment: @MarcGravell I'm not fully sure what the OP meant by my score .. **my tag score**, isn't updating immediately. I got my rep from a bunch of C# questions and then suddenly a few days later my tag score on my profile bumped up. Is it cached or something?

Answer (score 4):

If you answer a question and you answer is community wiki, you do not get rep gains or losses on the votes.

If you have gone over the 200 reputation per day limit, you will no longer gain rep until the server time hits midnight (which is right around 8pm EST right now).

Answer (score 2):

*recently answered a whole bunch of questions on Stackoverflow, but they've not modified my score. Is there any reason would this be happening?*

An obvious point but, for the sake of anyone finding this question at a future date who does not realise:

The reputation score does not increase when you answer questions but if and when others vote for answers you have given (and, as already stated, votes for answers that are marked 'community wiki' do not affect reputation score).